# editable profile page

Tags: html, css, user-interface, razor, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap.

I want to create a profile page with an `edit` button on the top left.

When a user clicks on this button,

all the profile fields become editable

(I think `input` elements)

Any idea how to implement it most easily?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Not even sure how to approach this

Comment: @EladBenda start reading up on the [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable) tag, that is your fastest approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't count on everyone using HTML5, you could do it the hard way where you start with all fields either disabled or read only and then at the press of a button, you change the attribute. Using the same function, you could then show or enable the 'Save' button.  Something like...

```
// Lock or Unlock Controls ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function lockControls(setLock) {
   var bOk = setLock;
   $("#btnSave").attr('disabled', bOk);
   $("#emailMessage").attr('disabled', bOk);
   $("#emailSubject").attr('disabled', bOk);
   $("#buildingList").attr('disabled', bOk);
}
```